# Child element with 100% width for table with auto width columns

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table. Table already contains one row with two columns. Columns width are perfect for me. But afterwards using JS I add new row to the table with input element which I want to fill the cell as content for first cell and columns width changed.

Easier to show rather than describe:

[image: layout]
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15612314/Layout.png

The question it how to keep previous width for columns without explicit setting width for all columns?

Thanks

Comment: Actually I mean <input style="width: 100%"/>. But anyway - width changed for column(

Comment: obviously changed it because you didn't set the fixed width for the cell that's why it change it. ok cell width for 1st is whatever now you add another row and in that you another element set as 100% so what mean for the table that this cell contain stretch and give the 100% to it and adjust the another cell with this

Comment: you need to set the fixed width for one of the column

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage jquery to acheive this, since you are already using javascript. Ading something this will do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input:text").css("width", "100%")
    })
</script>
```